# Conceptual Stucture doesn't accept clust

Tags: r

I use the latest version of package and I try to run this:
I try to run [this](https://bibliometrix.org/documents/bibliometrix_Report.html#co-word-analysis-through-correspondence-analysis) example:

```
library(bibliometrix)
download.file("https://www.bibliometrix.org/datasets/joi.zip", destfile = temp<-tempfile())
M <- convert2df(readLines(unz(temp, "joi.txt")), dbsource="isi",format="plaintext")
CS <- conceptualStructure(M, method="MCA", field="ID", minDegree=10, clust=5, stemming=FALSE, labelsize=8,documents=20)
```

but I receive this error:

> ```
> Error in conceptualStructure(M, method = "MCA", field = "ID", minDegree = 10,  : 
>   unused argument (clust = 5)
> ```

What should change?

Comment: Hey.. I am on R 3.6.1 and bibliometrix 2.3.2. I don't get that error with your code and I get 5 clusters